# Does this sort of attemted bridging of disciplines equal more than adding parts or is it trivial to a person understanding each discipline?

Tags: interdisciplinary

Scribbled notes
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: cosinus distributed over tangent tangens plane]
cosinus distributed over tangent tangens plane

```
from math import pi, tan, cos
from matplotlib import pyplot

x_tan = []
y_0 = []
y_cos = []

bound = pi/2
sieve = 1000
for column in range(sieve):
    x_tan.append(tan(bound*column/sieve))
    y_cos.append(cos(bound*column/sieve))
    y_0.append(0)

pyplot.plot(x_tan, y_0)#Graph
pyplot.plot(x_tan, y_cos)#Graph
pyplot.show()#Graph
```

Comment: 1. It would be best if you could but clarify your question. I am not really sure what you are even asking for. 2. Guessing it’s about application of trig functions to economics that is problematic- in economics there are almost no regular cycles/waves that would require modeling with trig function - fun fact most mathematics for economics books will not even cover trig functions and rather spend more time on optimization